# How to translate a JSON string using HTTP-API for deployment to corresponding CLI format command?

Tags: curl, deployment, command-line-interface, wildfly

I want to write a shell script using Wildfly-HTTP-API to deploy wars instead of the cli, which appears to be not so efficient as expected. I have found one script, part of it is:

```
echo "-> Upload new war"
bytes_value=`curl -sF "file=@${WAR_PATH}/${WAR_NAME}" --digest ${WILDFLY_MANAGEMENT_URL}/management/add-content | perl -pe 's/^.*"BYTES_VALUE"\s*:\s*"(.*)".*$/$1/'`
echo $bytes_value

json_string_start='{"content":[{"hash": {"BYTES_VALUE" : "'
json_string_end='"}}], "address": [{"deployment":"'"${WAR_NAME}"'"}], "operation":"add", "enabled":"true"}'
json_string="$json_string_start$bytes_value$json_string_end"

echo "-> Deploy new war"
result=`curl -sS -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json_string" --digest ${WILDFLY_MANAGEMENT_URL}/management | perl -pe 's/^.*"outcome"\s*:\s*"(.*)".*$/$1/'`
echo $result
```

I am used to translate JSON strings into CLI commands, but the step

```
'{"content":[{"hash": {"BYTES_VALUE" : "$bytes_value"}}], "address": [{"deployment":"${WAR_NAME}"}], "operation":"add", "enabled":"true"}'
```

makes me confused because I couldn't find the corresponding command for CLI using /deployment segment:

```
[domain@$ip:9990 /] /deployment=${WAR_NAME}:add(content=[hash=
```

I don't know how to complete it, Would anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload content you can use streams (those are coming to the CLI in WildFly 11). The cli uses the Http-API (at least in Wildfly 10) as this is the default management interface.
The hash is the digest of the uploaded content, you should /deployment=${WAR_NAME}:add(content=[bytes= to add the content itself or use the url parameter (a file url does work if you are on the same machine as the DC).

You may take a look at : [the documentation of the API](https://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/10.0.0.Final/deployment/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I still haven't figured it out because I never had a case like this. I got "failure-description" => {"domain-failure-description" => "JBAS014749: Operation handler failed: null"}" whatever I put after "add(content=[bytes="(or hash, url, path). Would you please give me a complete example so that I can better understand this operation?  Thank you very much!

Comment: /deployment=test.war:add(content=[{url=file:///home/ehsavoie/test.war}], runtime-name=webcontext.war)

Comment: I've tried the command above and finally passed this step. Thanks a lot.